# Linked list with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

Good morning, I'm learning and I want to make a Linked List with recursive function, I was looking for examples but I only found examples in Java or other types.
From what I saw I suppose it would be something like that, but I can't get it to work. If someone could help me I would appreciate it very much.
Thank you.

---

```
function ListRecurse () {
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
}
function Node () {
    this.data = data; 
    this.next = next;
}
ListRecurse.prototype.add = function (data) {
    let NewNode = new Node(this.add(data), null)
    if (this.head === null) {
        this.head = NewNode;
    }
    else {
        let current = this.head;
        while (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current = NewNode
    }
    this.size ++;
}
```

---

Comment: In your `Node` constructor, you are using `data` and `next` variables, but those are defined nowhere. You need to use function parameters. Also, the first thing your `add` method does is call `add` again, it's going to be infinite

Comment: do you have an example of the call of the recursive function and the wanted result of it with more than one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your implementation:

1. Your use of recursion is going to lead to a stack overflow:

   ```
       let newNode = new Node(this.add(data));
   ```

   This will just keep calling itself without end. The code that you have below this statement will never be executed. Recursion always needs a base case, which will stop the recursion.
2. The `Node` constructor lacks parameters, so the variables `data` and `next` do not exist.
3. When assigning `NewNode`, you should not assign it to `current`, as that will break the list. You should assign it to `current.next`

With those problems fixed, it will work, but also take into account these remarks:

- Don't name variables with an initial capital, as it is common practice to reserve such notation for constructors (classes). So I would use the name `newNode` instead of `NewNode`
- Use default values for parameters which you might not use in a call. In your case you could give `next` a default value of `null`, so that you don't need to specify `null` in the call of `Node`.
- Use the modern `class` syntax for your constructors. It leads to cleaner code.
- Allow the `add` method to be chained. So make it return `this`.

So the recursive implementation could look like this:

```js
class Node {
    // Accept arguments (the second one could be optional)
    constructor(data, next=null) {
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = next;
    }
    lastNode() { // new method that uses recursion
        return this.next?.lastNode() || this;
    }
}


class ListRecurse {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    add(data) {
        let newNode = new Node(data); // No second argument. It has a default value
        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            // The lastNode implementation uses recursion:
            this.head.lastNode().next = newNode;
        }
        this.size ++;
        return this; // to allow chaining
    }
}

let list = new ListRecurse();
list.add(1).add(2).add(3);
console.log(list);
```

The recursion now happens in this statement, which may need some explanation:

```
return this.next?.lastNode() || this;
```

This will check if the current node has a next node reference. If so, the recursive call to `lastNode` is made. If not, then we are in the "base case": the expression with the optional chaining operator (`?.`) is `undefined` and the OR operator (`||`) will then kick in to have `this` returned, since it is the final node in the chain.

### More efficient

First, the use of recursion here might be a nice exercise, but it doesn't give much benefit. An iterative solution is fine.

It is a pity however that you need to walk along the whole linked list every time you want to add a node. As @Nina already answered, you can avoid this inefficiency by maintaining a reference to the tail node.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the advantage of storing the last node and return `this` for have a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

```js
function ListRecurse() {
    this.head = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

function Node(data, next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

ListRecurse.prototype.add = function(data) {
    const node = new Node(data, null);
    if (this.head === null) this.head = node;
    else this.last.next = node;
    this.last = node;  
    this.size++;
    return this;
}

const list = new ListRecurse().add(1).add(2).add(3);

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```